# retrieve the value of datagridview inside the panel in splitcontainer

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a split container control in c#. inside the right panel there is a datagridview.  i have  a button in panel outside the datagridview. when the button is clicked  i want to get the datagridview's selected row value. how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem
```

or

```
dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[x].Value
```

where x is the column index

or

```
sensorDataGridView.CurrentCell.Value
```